# How to render image inside a form in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6

I've try to render an image inside the form but still doesnt render anything

Here's custom module

```
$image_options = array(
    'path' => 'http://novelplanet.com/Content/images/noImage.jpg', 
    'alt' => 'Test alt',
    'title' => 'Test title',
    'width' => '50%',
    'height' => '50%',
    'attributes' => array('class' => 'image', 'id' => 'my-img'),
    );


    $image = theme('image', $image_options);

    $form['y']['image_div'] = array(
      '#prefix' => '<div class="image">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#markup' => $image,
    );
```

in my tpl

```
<?php print drupal_render($form['y']['image_div']); ?>
```

How do I render image inside the form.inc drupal 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the theme method as follows:

```
theme('image', $path, $alt = '', $title = '', $attributes = NULL, 
       $getsize = TRUE);
```

you can also use

```
theme('imagecache', $presetname, $path, $alt = '', $title = '',
       $attributes = NULL, $getsize = TRUE);
```

if you use the ImageCache module.